# Hibernate Upgrade to 5.5.15 is compelling me to add into Query object with new class type argument

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics

I am using hibernate 5.6.15 and i have overridden the methods of hibernate template , one of them being findByNamedParam(), it uses the Query object which has query string to hit the database and fetch results for you.

```
@Override
public <T> List<T> findByNamedParam( @Language( "HQL" ) final String queryString, final String[] paramNames, final Object[] values, int maxResults ) throws DataAccessException
{
    if ( ( paramNames == null ? 0 : paramNames.length ) != ( values == null ? 0 : values.length ) )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Length of paramNames array must match length of values array" );
    }

    return executeWithNativeSession( session -> {
        Query queryObject = session.createQuery( queryString );
        prepareQuery( queryObject );
        queryObject.setMaxResults( maxResults );
        if ( values != null )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ )
            {
                queryObject.setParameter( paramNames[ i ], values[ i ] );
            }
        }
        return queryObject.getResultList();
    } );
}
```

But now the Query is removed and the new versions use

```
Query<T> queryObject = session.createQuery( queryString, EntityClass );
```

Where  is the type of Class used by Database objects , so in order to fullfill this requirement , we have to pass the Entity class in the Create query session. And this can be fetched only from the class where this findByNameParam is called.

So it will look something like this :

```
Class A { Public List<**EntityClass**> method 1(){

//some code 
// return to call for find by name parameter 

return hibernateOperations.findByNamedParam( hql, params.toArray( new String[ params.size() ] ), values.toArray(),**EntityClass**, getBatchSize() ); } }
```

And in `HibernateTemplateExtension` Class(where i have over riddden the `findByNamedParam()` method) I can define the `findByNamedParam()` with one extra argument

```
public <T> List<T> findByNamedParam( @Language( "HQL" ) final String queryString, final String[] paramNames, final Object[] values,Class<T> EntityClass, int maxResults ) throws DataAccessException`
```

and use it in query object like this

```
Query<T> queryObject = session.createQuery( queryString, EntityClass );
```

Easy???

Well i would have to change 100s of method calls like i did above in Class A just to make the Query object work. And i am not able to find any alternative solution to this.

I used the below code inside the hibernateExtension CLass and used it in my `findByNamedParam()` method.

The code that I added :

```java
private final static class DummyClass<T>
    {
        private DummyClass()
        {
        }
    }

private static <T> Class<T> getTypeClass()
    {
        DummyClass<T> instance = new DummyClass<T>();
        TypeVariable<?>[] parameters = instance.getClass().getTypeParameters();

        return (Class<T>)parameters[ 0 ].getClass();
    }
```

Then used it inside the findByNamedParam() method like this :

```
@Override

public <T> List<T> findByNamedParam( @Language( "HQL" ) final String queryString, final String[] paramNames, final Object[] values, int maxResults ) throws DataAccessException
{
    if ( ( paramNames == null ? 0 : paramNames.length ) != ( values == null ? 0 : values.length ) )
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Length of paramNames array must match length of values array" );
    }

    Class<T> typeClass = getTypeClass();
    return executeWithNativeSession( session -> {
        Query<T> queryObject = session.createQuery( queryString, typeClass );
        prepareQuery( queryObject );
        queryObject.setMaxResults( maxResults );
        if ( values != null )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < values.length; i++ )
            {
                queryObject.setParameter( paramNames[ i ], values[ i ] );
            }
        }
        return queryObject.getResultList();
    } );
}
```

But this is also not working because the Query expects a real Entity class object and not the genric class object , Below is the error i am facing while doing the above :

```
Type specified for TypedQuery [sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl] is incompatible with query return type [class com.junifer.thor.database.hibernate.objects.UkTradingUnitMode]
```

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work anymore! Next to that the `HibernateTemplate` is also something you shouldn't be using anymore but rather the plain `EntityManager` of `SessionFactory` instead. The `HibernateTemplate` exists as a migration strategy and actually has been removed in the most recent version of Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum The requirement is related to upgrading the hibernate to the more recent version and hibernate 5.6.15 actually has removed the usage of Query and introduced Query<T>. I have fixed it in my question.

Comment: And where does my statement says otherwise? I'm merely mentioning that the use of `HibernateTemplate` is deprecated as well and that you should use the `SessionFactory` directly. Is this painful probably but the same is to be said for using the extended `HibernateTemplate`. The latter will even break or prevent you from upgrading Spring to a newer version.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).